# How to graph the max and min values of a sheet?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, stylesheet, style, maximum

Hi I just start working in Mathematica version 10.3.1 and I want to graph a sheet of data that I created in Excel (yeah i use Windows). The problem is i have so many data; 200 columns and 50 row of information, so i want plot all this, but after plotting, obviously, it looks very messy. So what i want to do is just show the max values and the min values in the plot. I really don't know how to do it, some help will be very appreciated.

The code that i used to make the graph is:

```
grap = Transpose[
Import["C:\\Users\\Damian\\Documents\\Tablas\\Modelo \pob standar output.csv"]]

Dimensions[grap]
ListLinePlot[grap, ImageSize -> 700]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this which can give you the max Points and their positions.

```
points = With[{p = Ordering[#, -1] & /@ grap}, 
   MapThread[Flatten[{#, #2[[#1]]}] &, {p, grap}]];
```

To show the points in the plot you can use:

```
ListLinePlot[grap, ImageSize -> 700,Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[points]}];
```

To plot them alone you can just `ListPlot[points]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It almost work but seems that some points were missing in the function. Also, this doesn't work to mark the min value points (so sorry, i don't catch how do you use the # in the function). 
.